# php read the .txt files in a folder and then count the line break

Tags: php, php-5.6

I basically use this code to paste the lines from a txt to php and it works fine now I would like to tell those lines, I found almost nothing that is similar to what I am doing

```
<?php

                    $files = glob('../examples/upload/*.txt');
                    foreach($files as $file)
                    {
                       if(($fh = fopen($file, 'r')) != false)
                       {
                          while(!feof($fh))
                          {

                            printf("<tr><td><div>%s</div>\n", fgets($fh));
                          }
                          fclose($fh);
                       }
                    }

                  ?>
```

Currently this code works:

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("pages/examples/upload/cuenta1.txt", "r");
    $members = array();
      while (!feof($file)) {
        $members[] = fgets($file);
      }
    fclose($file);
    echo count($members);
?>
```

But now I need you to read all the txt files that are in the folder and count the lines.

how could I do?, try many ways but they do not work.

Comment: Don't use `while(!feof($fh))` when reading a file. Use `while ($line = fgets($fh))`

Comment: Thanks for that information, but would you know how to tell the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over all the files like in the first code, then add up the counts.

```
$total = 0;
$files = glob('../examples/upload/*.txt');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $total += count(file($file));
}
echo $total;
```

The `file()` function does what your second code snippet does, so you don't have to write your own loop.

Comment: Thank you very much !!, I was trying to fix that problem 5 hours ago, really thank you very much !!!